# Get Posts (Wall Facebook) of me and my friends

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I use
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/

I create an App. I want get Posts of the wall of me and my friends.

I try `me/feed` and `me/posts` but I get nothing.

I have this unit test.

Any suggestions?

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Basic_using_SDK()
    {
        // http://blog.prabir.me/posts/facebook-csharp-sdk-making-requests
        var fb = new Facebook.FacebookClient();

        var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)fb.Get("4");

        var id = (string)result["id"];
        var name = (string)result["name"];
        var firstName = (string)result["first_name"];
        var lastName = (string)result["last_name"];
        var link = (string)result["link"];
        var username = (string)result["username"];
        var gender = (string)result["gender"];
        var male = (string)result["locale"];


        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        parameters["fields"] = "id,name";

        result = (IDictionary<string, object>)fb.Get("4", parameters);
        id = (string)result["id"];
        name = (string)result["name"];


        dynamic result2 = fb.Get("4");

        id = result2.id;
        name = result2.name;
        firstName = result2.first_name;
        lastName = result2.last_name;
        link = result2.link;
        username = result2.username;
        gender = result2.gender;
        male = result2.locale;


        dynamic parameters2 = new ExpandoObject();
        parameters2.fields = "id,name";

        dynamic result3 = fb.Get("4", parameters);
        id = result3.id;
        name = result3.name;

        dynamic me = fb.Get("zuck");
        firstName = me.first_name;
        lastName = me.last_name;


        var client = new FacebookClient(AccessToken);
        dynamic me2 = client.Get("me");
        string aboutMe = me2.about;

        dynamic result4 = client.Get("/me/feed");

        foreach (dynamic post in result4.data)
        {
            var fromName = post.from.name;
            Console.WriteLine(fromName);
        }

        dynamic result5 = client.Get("/me/posts");
        for (int i = 0; i < result5.Count; i++)
        {
        }


        // https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=xxxxxxx
        // https://graph.facebook.com/xxxxxxx
        var uidKiquenet = "xxxxx";
        var query = string.Format(@"SELECT status_id,message,time,source,uid,place_id
                            FROM status WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid FROM status WHERE uid = '" + uidKiquenet + "') ORDER BY time DESC");

        dynamic parameters6 = new ExpandoObject();
        parameters6.q = query;

        dynamic results6 = fb.Get("/xxxxx?fields=id,name,age_range,about,email,first_name,gender");


        string myMessage = "Hello from Test";

        fb.PostTaskAsync("me/feed", new { message = myMessage }).ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            if (!t.IsFaulted)
            {
                string message = "Great, your message has been posted to you wall!";
                Console.WriteLine(message);
            }
        });

        fb.GetTaskAsync("me").ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            if (!t.IsFaulted)
            {
                var result11 = (IDictionary<string, object>)t.Result;
                string myDetails = string.Format("Your name is: {0} {1} and your Facebook profile Url is: {3}",
                                                  (string)result11["first_name"], (string)result11["last_name"],
                                                  (string)result11["link"]);
                Console.WriteLine(myDetails);
            }
        });

        // This uses Facebook Query Language
        // See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/ for more information.
        query = string.Format("SELECT uid,name,pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1={0}) ORDER BY name ASC", "me()");

        fb.GetTaskAsync("fql", new { q = query }).ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            if (!t.IsFaulted)
            {
                var result1 = (IDictionary<string, object>)t.Result;
                var data = (IList<object>)result1["data"];
                var count = data.Count;
                var message = string.Format("You have {0} friends", count);
                Console.WriteLine(message);

                foreach (IDictionary<string, object> friend in data)
                    Console.WriteLine((string)friend["name"]);
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: You do know that FQL is deprecated and does not work in newer apps anymore, right? anyway, are you using a user access token with the correct permission?

Comment: In review status **https://developers.facebook.com/apps/xxxxx/review-status/** for my App (in development) by default permissions are: ***email, public_profile, user_friends***

Comment: not sure why you want to go through the review process though, while your app is not even finished...

Comment: For testing purposes

Comment: why would you go through the review process for testing? didn´t you read the docs?

Comment: i´ve added a link to my answer, about login review.

Comment: _“In review status […] for my App (in development) by default permissions are: […]”_ – those are the three permissions that are _approved by Facebook_ by default, meaning they do not need to get submitted for review. It does _not_ mean that they will be _granted by the user of your app_ automatically – you still need to ask each single user for them via the login flow.

Answer (score 1):

You must authorize with the correct permission in order to get access to feed posts. Try authorizing with `user_posts`, as it is explained in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/feed#read

Be aware that this does not get you access to posts of friends, unless they posted on the wall of the authorized user.

About review, you may want to read this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/faqs#what_is_review

Btw, FQL is deprecated and will only work in v2.0 Apps - not in newer ones.

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happened to me . Here is my Solution

I made my project registered on Facebook developer console. Then I did my code same as you but could not get posts / information . After some time i submitted my application for app review to facebook team (it was still in early development phase) and after their feedback I got my code working . So pending Application review can be your issue also . This option is available in application setting . Give it a shot

**Update**
Another code sample is here

```
 if (Request["code"] == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect(string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}",
                    FB_app_id, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, FB_scope));
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                Dictionary<string, string> tokens = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                string url = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}&code={3}&client_secret={4}&perms=status_update"
                    , FB_app_id, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, FB_scope, Request["code"].ToString(), FB_secret_id);
                HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
                using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
                {

                    StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

                    string vals = rd.ReadToEnd();
                    foreach (string token in vals.Split('&'))
                    {
                        tokens.Add(token.Substring(0, token.IndexOf('=')), token.Substring(token.IndexOf("=") + 1, token.Length - token.IndexOf('=') - 1));
                    }
                    string access_token = tokens["access_token"];
                    Session["fb_access_token"] = access_token;

                    return true;


                }

            }
```

Comment: sample in ASPX page , not Unit Test ? requires **Response, Request** ?

Comment: There is no issue in using them and I'm using cshtml files instead of aspx file